# lower resolution maintaining aspect ration with center feeting

Tags: display, resolution

I wanted to acheive something like what was implemented in Windows. Lower resolution of the display, without stretching, that is centered display, which was shown on the first image on Windows. [image]

But In linux, I couldn't do that. I was able to get to lower resolution without stretching, but the display isnt on center.

I have followed the following question on AskUbuntu and done my own research. My display is an external monitor with HDMI connection.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/264573/changing-to-a-lower-screen-resolution-without-stretching